# Money for survival or passion in suffering?

Tags: software-industry, quitting, career-switch

I started off as an intern in engineering company before deciding to work a little with them when I was offered the position of a technical officer. I loved this job until I bordom kicked in. That's when l found love in IT.

I lost my first job some weeks ago, but before then, I had fallen in love with software engineering industry, which I have been trying to develop myself in for quite sometime now.

As you had imagined, I still have my academic career to pursue which requires money. Parents has offered to help but at 25 I feel I will be a burden to them so this is my responsibility.

I have an enticing offer from an engineering company which will be tasky but can put some food on the table, pay the rent, and tuition fees with left over. 
And at the other hand my love for software development is burning hot, I have applied to dozens company for an internship opportunity with no invite till now, my programming capabilities is still very rusty with a long way to go, struggling to make ends meet.

The catch is that I have potential to turn things around if I am exposed to industry practice. But for now I need money and I want to become a software developer. 
I seek answers from only those with similar experience on how they handled their case

Comment: We can't really tell you what direction to take your career path in - that's out of scope for this community.  You might want to read the [help page](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/tour) for what's appropriate to ask here.

Comment: Don't ask "what do I do"? That's generally not accepted as a question here.

Comment: Suffer now to be happy in the future. It will be easier to get a job later on with some form of training.

Comment: You can do both. Start a career in engineering, and build your software development skills privately. As a matter of fact, people who can code _and_ know something else well (such as engineering) are often highly sought after - so you can transition to SW engineering later.

Answer (score 6):

So... you don't actually have to have a degree in CS to pursue a career in IT. In fact, if you already have a degree in an engineering-related field and get yourself up to speed in software development, that will very likely open doors for you that regular CS majors won't get (and your job experience, however slight, will help even more).

If you want to learn the trade, I'd recommend going to a bootcamp or taking courses at a local community college. If you really, really want to go back to school to get a second degree, you certainly can, but I'd go so far as to say that the things that you learn in a CS degree are not always anywhere near as directly applicable to the real world as those first two options I mentioned (and plus, a degree, especially a post-bac one, is probably far more expensive as well).